# ¿Cómo crear divs en cada celda de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, dom

El enunciado es el siguiente:

- Un div con id animales que funcionará como contenedor de los animales
  de la página.
- Una serie de divs con clase animal que se generarán dinámicamente y
  se
     añadirán al contenedor. Cada div tendrá clase animal (lo que le da las
     características CSS comunes a todos los animales), el id correspondiente al
     animal que estamos generando (lo que permitirá acceder a él de manera
     individualizada) y la imagen de fondo con el nombre del animal.

Como la imagen es una imagen 2x2, con una forma de cuadrado, con 2 columnas y 2 filas, he creado una tabla **mediante DOM** con un div contenedor llamado .

Ahora el problema es el siguiente, ¿cómo asigno a cada celda de la tabla el div con la clase = animal, y el id correspondiente al animal (vaca, cerdo, perro, gato; uno por cada celda).

```js
/*Registro un evento para cuando termine de cargarse el documento se cargen los eventos necesarios.*/
window.onload = crearTabla;

/*Array donde estan definidos los nombres de los animales.*/
var animales = ["cerdo", "vaca", "gato", "perro"];

/*Exclusivamente con DOM, crear una tabla 2x2 (4 elementos-casillas).*/
function crearTabla() {
 //Obtener la referencia del elemento body.
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 
 //Creamos el elemento/objeto que deseamos: <div>.
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 //Asignamos un id al div creado.
 div.setAttribute("id", "animales");
 //Agregamos al body el div.
 body.appendChild(div);
  
 //Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>.
 var tabla = document.createElement("table");
 var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
 //Crea las celdas.
 for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
  //Crea las hileras de la tabla.
  var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var j=0; j<2; j++) {
   var celda = document.createElement("td");
   var textoCelda = document.createTextNode("Hilera "+i+", Columna "+j);
   celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
   hilera.appendChild(celda);
  }
  //Agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody).
  tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
 }
 
 //Posiciona el <tbody> debajo del elemento <table>.
 tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
 //appends <table> into <body>.
 div.appendChild(tabla);
 //Modifica el atributo "border" de la tabla y lo fija a "2";
 tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```css
html{
 height:100%;
}

body{
 background-color:#FFE0B2;
 margin:0px;
 height: 100%;
}


#animales{
 width:500px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#FF9900;
 border-left:2px solid black;
 border-right:2px solid black;
}

#animales:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.animal{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 margin:25px;
 float:left;
 background-size: contain;

}

.rota{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 
  transition: transform 4s;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 4s;  
}

@keyframes gran
{
 0%{}
 50%{ transform: scale(2,2);} 
 100%{ transform: scale(1,1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes gran{
 0%{}
 50%{ -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);}
 100%{ -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);} 
}

@-o-keyframes gran{
 0%{}
 50%{ -o-transform: scale(2,2);}
 100%{ -o-transform: scale(1,1);} 
}


.grande{
 animation: gran 4s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation: gran 4s ease-out;
 -moz-animation: gran 4s ease-out;
 -o-animation: gran 4s ease-out;
}





@keyframes peque
{
 0%{}
 50%{ transform: scale(0.5,0.5);} 
 100%{ transform: scale(1,1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes peque{
 0%{}
 50%{ -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);}
 100%{ -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);} 
}

@-o-keyframes peque{
 0%{}
 50%{ -o-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);}
 100%{ -o-transform: scale(1,1);} 
}


.pequenio{
 animation: peque 4s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation: peque 4s ease-out;
 -moz-animation: peque 4s ease-out;
 -o-animation: peque 4s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>Animales!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/estilo.css"/>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/animales.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

He insertado los nombres "Hilera 0, Columna 0"... para haber pruebas, pero tendrían que ir las imágenes de las fotos en esas celdas/divs.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp aquí tienes algo que te ayudará

Comment: Si entendí bien lo que quieres, puedes entonces recorrer los td de la tabla con un foreach y agregarle los div a cada celda con la funcion .append() o .html() de JQuery, es la forma mas facil que se me ocurre

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conformar un array bidimensional con los animales en los cuales las posiciones coincidan con cómo quieres que aparezcan en la tabla:

```
array_animales[0][0] = "vaca";
array_animales[0][1] = "gato";
array_animales[1][0] = "perro";
array_animales[1][1] = "mono";
```

Y haces los llamas por posición en base a los valores de `i` y `j` con los que construyes tu tabla, tras crear el elemento `td` le añades el atributo de clase coincidente con la posición en el array.